# MySQL column order in composite key

Tags: mysql, key, composite

I have a doubt, Here is my table:

```
mysql> show create table watchdog\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   Table: watchdog
   Create Table: CREATE TABLE `watchdog` (
       `index1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `index2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `dog` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '9',
        PRIMARY KEY (`index1`,`index2`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

<1>
First query:

```
select index1, index2 
from watchdog 
where index1 > 4000008 and index1 < 4200007;
```

Result:

```
 ...
| 4200001 | 4200002 |
| 4200002 | 4200003 |
| 4200003 | 4200004 |
| 4200004 | 4200005 |
| 4200005 | 4200006 |
| 4200006 | 4200007 |
+---------+---------+

199997 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

<2>
Second query:

```
select index1, index2 
from watchdog 
where index2 > 4000009 and index2 < 4200007;
```

Result:

```
...
| 4200002 | 4200003 |
| 4200003 | 4200004 |
| 4200004 | 4200005 |
| 4200005 | 4200006 |
+---------+---------+

199997 rows in set (1.68 sec)
```

The time they used are 0.9sec and 1.68sec! Could anyone tell me why? What is the matter with the composite key order?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL has good [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on composite indexes, which you should review.  Let me summarize the issue for you query.

The pertinent part of the query is the `where` clause:

```
where index1 > 4000008 and index1 < 4200007;
index2 > 4000009 and index2 < 4200007;
```

You have an index on `index1, index2`, in that order.  In general, MySQL can look at a query and do one of three things with the index:

1. Decide not to use the index at all (based on statistics or inapplicability to the query)
2. Decide to use `index1` component.
3. Decide to use `index1` component *and* `index2`.

In the first query, MySQL can choose the second option.  So, it uses the index for the `index1` comparison.  It then presumably scans the appropriate rows, looking at `index2` value in the index, finds the row ids, looks them up, and returns the rows.

For the second `where` clause, it cannot use the index.  The index's first key is `index1`, and it is not present in the query.  So, MySQL has to do a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined a **composite** key which can only be used if both columns or the first column are used in your `where` clause.

But you only use the second column of your key in the slow query.